# Publishing Office add-ins targeting larger organizations and enterprises using Partner Center

Tags: office-js

Office add-ins are now published using the Partner Center instead of the seller dashboard.
In the seller dashboard there was a field "Testing notes" which was used to provide information needed for testing and was also the way to tell Microsoft if the add-in targets larger organizations and enterprises, which changes some validation policies.

Since the [validation policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies#7-apps-and-add-ins-are-easily-identified-and-understood) (chapter 7.4.5) still mention and link the respective [blog entry](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/office-store-validation-policy-changes-to-support-apps-and-add-ins-that-target-larger-organizations-and-enterprises/) I guess this is still possible, but I didn't find the place to add this information in Partner Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the "Review and Publish" page there is a "Notes to certification" which is the new method of adding these testing notes.

[image]